# remove comma in jsonpath template using bash

Tags: json, linux, bash, jsonpath

I have a JSON path template query.

```
oc get event jsonpath='{range .items[*]},{@.name}{","}{@.message}{","}{@.evenname}'{"\n"}{end}'> /tmp/test.csv
```

i'm redirecting it to csv.

```
name1,message of event one,eventname1
name2,message of,event,two,eventname2
name3,message of event three,eventname3
name4,message of, event four,eventname4
```

getting comma in a message from above output , i want to replace the comma with space for the second column(message) in the bash script.

Anyone has any thoughts on how can achieve this.

Expected result

```
name1,message of event one,eventname1
name2,message of event two,eventname2
name3,message of event three,eventname3
name4,message of event four,eventname4
```

Comment: please update the question with: the code you've tried, the (wrong) result generated by your code and the (correct) expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can change the field delimiter to a character known to not exist in the data (eg, `|`), you would now be generating:

```
name1|message of event one|eventname1
name2|message of,event,two|eventname2
name3|message of event three|eventname3
name4|message of, event four|eventname4
```

From here we can use `sed` to **a)** remove/replace `,` with `<space>` and then **b)** replace `|` with `,`:

```
$ sed 's/[ ]*,[ ]*/,/g;s/,/ /g;s/|/,/g'
```

**NOTE:** the `s/[ ]*,[ ]*/g` is needed to address the additional requirement of stripping out repeating spaces (as would occur in line #4 if we replace `,` with `<space>`)

When applied to the data this generates:

```
name1,message of event one,eventname1
name2,message of event two,eventname2
name3,message of event three,eventname3
name4,message of event four,eventname4
```

---

Another option using `awk` (for OP's current data using the `,` as the field delimiter):

```
awk -F',' '                              # input field delimiter = ","
{ x=$1","                                # start new string as field #1 + ","

  sep=""                                 # initial separator = "" for fields 2 to (NF-1)

  for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {                   # loop through fields 2 to (NF-1)
      gsub(/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/,"",$i)          # trim leading/trailing spaces
      x=x sep $i                         # append current field to x along with sep
      sep=" "                            # use " " as separator for rest of fields
  }

  printf "%s,%s\n", x, $NF               # print "x" plus "," plus the last field (NF)
}'
```

When applied to the data this generates:

```
name1,message of event one,eventname1
name2,message of event two,eventname2
name3,message of event three,eventname3
name4,message of event four,eventname4
```